# msp430g2553 How to share datas from board to VS for C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, embedded, msp430

I wanna make a project with msp430g2553 like use heat sensor and want to read the datas from the sensor on the program that I write on C#. I know the basics of C# I can build form applications and also can use msp430 boards but i don't know how to link them each other. I ask that how can I link each other?

But I want to write the all codes C# and msp430. I don't want to prepared GUI.

I searched a little bit there is something like GIOP to do that but there is information little about that. Can you help me please.

And thanks for helps.

Comment: I assume your C# program runs on your computer. So you need to create establish a communication between your server and your board.

There are a lot a solution for, the easiest is maybe to use USART.

Comment: Do you have just the chip or the development kit?  The part has a UART that you can connected to you PC.  Not sure if it is a USB or 9-Pin serial port.  It would depend on the connector and the BAUD rate.  You would also may need the vendor driver if it is USB.

Comment: Development kit. I use Msp430g2553 launch pad.  Not only chip.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) that you should use the UART feature from the Launchpad development board. Just find the guide for your board and look for the basic demo that outputs the "hello world" message to the serial port with connection to your PC using a terminal program such as Putty in serial mode. Then write a simple program in C# to replace the terminal program and establish that your program can read the "hello world" from the serial port. From there, you then need to change the demo to reading the sensor. I suggest you first emulate reading data from the sensor (i.e., must make up some data) and output that to the serial port, then finish your C# program with that data. Then find a suitable sensor and read the datasheet for the part. You may need to use another interface (such as SPI or I2C) to read form the sensor. This will depend on the sensor you choose. Best of luck!